# Converting list items to string, question on syntax?

Tags: python

I have converted items in a list to a string using the following:

```
target_ls = [w, x, y, z]

    as_str = (str (y) for y in target_ls)

    final_str = "\t".join(as_str) + "\n"
```

But I notice that I can also use:

```
as_str = [str (y) for y in target_ls]
final_str = "\t".join(as_str) + "\n"
```

The result for both is the same. Does using square brackets instead of parentheses (or vice-versa) matter in this case?

Thank you

Comment: what are `w, x, y, z`? please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

when you write `as_str = [str (y) for y in target_ls]` it creates a list and keep in memory but `as_str = (str (y) for y in target_ls)` is a generator, so it will not keep anything in memory once you iterate over it, it will do a 'lazy execution' and give you the desired result.

Generators are memory efficient but can be used only once.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Brackets allocate a new list. In case you have many elements, this will allocate a lot of memory needlessly; use parentheses.

Parentheses create a generator. A generator can be used only once; if you need to reuse `as_str` again, use brackets.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for